# Long press on AndroidElement in Appium

Tags: testing, automation, appium

I`m trying to perform a long press action on AndroidElement in Appium. What I found is that i need to perform a TouchAction on this element, but... it only takes as argument WebDriver, no AndroidDriver that I`m using. For this reason it will not work.

```
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction(AndroidDriver);
    action.longPress(element, 10000);
```

I was looking for some answer for some time. LongPress (or something similar) is used in last test that I`m writting right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction();
action.longPress(webElement).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround could be usage of `io.appium.java_client.MultiTouchAction`.

```
MultiTouchAction multiTouch = new MultiTouchAction(AndroidDriver);
multiTouch.add(createTap(element, duration));
multiTouch.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will perform single tap and long press for particular period of time in android app

Make use of it

```
package com.prac.com;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.TapOptions.tapOptions;
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.LongPressOptions.longPressOptions;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import static java.time.Duration.ofSeconds;
import static io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.ElementOption.element;


    public class UdmeyCode extends Demo4TestBase {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver=Capabilities();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Views']").click();
            //Tap
            TouchAction t =new TouchAction(driver);
            WebElement expandList=  driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Expandable Lists']");
            t.tap(tapOptions().withElement(element(expandList))).perform();
            driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='1. Custom Adapter']").click();
        WebElement pn=  driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='People Names']");

            t.longPress(longPressOptions().withElement(element(pn)).withDuration(ofSeconds(2))).release().perform();
            //Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println(driver.findElementById("android:id/title").isDisplayed());







        }

    }
```